# Automatic suspension from review queue after I failed an ambiguous audit

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension, specific-audit

I have been suspended from the First Question review queue after I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/31951443).

This question contains an attached image with a long error message. I wanted to share feedback for the user to replace the image of the error message with actual text to make it easier to copy and paste.

After clicking 'share feedback' I got suspended.

What would have been the correct action for this question?

Comment: I also failed this audit, clicking `share feedback` and am suspended. I was thinking it could have had a bit more info since the code and image were the same and that pretty much was all that was posted, but I'm sure the expected answer was supposed to be `Looks Ok`.

Comment: Umm, while not as detailed as the screenshot, looks like the question *does* include enough textual error messages.

Comment: I would've noped that review with a skip. The way posts like that are handled basically 100% comes down to chance.

Comment: Imo this question's supposed action is ambiguous. @AndrewT.'s answer makes sense, but so does an additional comment to point the user to improve the question. Could this question be removed from the audit pool?

Comment: Side note: My understanding is that it takes more than one missed review to get a ban, but it would make a certain amount of twisted sense if the First post review queue triggered a ban on the First missed audit.

Comment: The correct action would have been to flag the question as being in need of improvement (i.e., to flag for closure), and choose the reason indicating that it lacks a minimal, reproducible example. No other action is defensible in this review queue. There is no need to "share feedback"; flagging the question as being in need of closure for the appropriate reason will have the same effect. (So, yes, the audit was bad, but your choice was still wrong.)

Comment: @notarobot click on 'flag' below the post, then 'needs improvement', then 'community specific reason', then 'needs debugging details'
I find this really user unfriendly. It would be better to make all available actions explicit by listing them on the right side.

Comment: @CodyGray I disagree: https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions . Share feedback if the post has the potential to be a good question, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post author. Choose from the standardized responses or leave a custom comment. You can either post a standardized comment as the Community bot or post as yourself and receive notifications.

Comment: @CodyGray and then so if thats case, and someone can't flag because they are suspended, then `Skip`? Is that how it should be handled?